# Уведомление о том, что файл не найден (gulp)?

Tags: gulp

```
gulp.src([
'folder/file.js', // ! нет файла
'folder/file2.js',
])
```

Если первый файл не найден то gulp всё равно продолжает сборку. Как сделать так чтобы он уведомлял об ошибке, что файла нет?

Comment: На en.se на аналогичные вопросы предлагаются разные варианты: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265677/how-to-get-gulp-to-error-on-missing-file), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209074/how-to-make-gulp-src-fail-if-a-file-is-missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте модуль `gulp-expect-file`

```
let expect = require('gulp-expect-file');

gulp.src([
'folder/file.js', // ! нет файла
'folder/file2.js',
])
.pipe(expect([
'folder/file.js', // ! нет файла
'folder/file2.js',
]))
```